# Using of PhotoChooserTask

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a list of images (as content) in my Windows Phone application. How can I see them with PhotoChooserTask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the basic and rough example of firing the task from a button click.

The below code uses a button click event to fire the PhotoChooserTask() and then place the selected image into a image control.

You will need to refercne the taskt using

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;
```

and then use the code as follows

```
public MainPage()
    {
    InitializeComponent();
        photoChooserTask = new PhotoChooserTask();
        photoChooserTask.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(photoChooserTask_Completed);
        }
        private void photochooserbtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
         {
         photoChooserTask.Show();
         }
        void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
         {
         if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
         {
         System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bmp =new     System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
         bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
         imagecontrol.Source = bmp;
         }
       }
```

Comment: thanks, but I have a list of images and i need to see all them

Comment: Sorry, I thought you wanted to get time images saved on the device. Shawn Kendrot's answer should suit what you want to do then as the photo chooser task isn't what you need.

Comment: Why do they make it so hard to find out information like this...? I was googling around for hours, with no success

Answer (score 1):

If you already have images that you pre-load with the application then you can display them like such:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}" Width="200"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

This assumes that the data context of your page has a property called "Images"

```
public IEnumerable<Uri> Images { get; set; }
```

And that you are populating that property like such:

```
Images = new List<Uri>
    {
        new Uri("Images/image1.png", UriKind.Relative),
        new Uri("Images/image2.png", UriKind.Relative),
        new Uri("Images/image3.png", UriKind.Relative),
        new Uri("Images/image4.png", UriKind.Relative)
    };
```

This assumes that you have put the images under an "Images" folder in your project and that the Build Action is set to Content

The above solution will give you a vertical list of the images. If you'd like to make it a little better then use the WP7 Toolkit and change the `ItemsPanel` of the `ListBox` to be a `WrapPanel`

```
   <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
       <ItemsPanelTemplate>
           <toolkit:WrapPanel/>
       </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the PhotoChooserTask to directly view pictures that you added to the project (as Content)... for that to work, you'll have to save the pictures to the Pictures Library (using the [MediaLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.aspx) class) before launching the PhotoChooserTask!

Comment: thanks, can you give me an example with source codes hot to display list of pictures from MediaLibrary using PhotoChooserTask ?

Comment: That's what I meant: the PhotoChooserTask shows the pictures *from* the  MediaLibrary only, so that you get "for free"!