# External Photo viewer (Windows Phone)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In this post: [Using of PhotoChooserTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10603764/using-of-photochoosertask/10603867#10603867) I have found out that it is possible to show picture from External Phone Photo Viewer. So I need to click on photo from Media galery and it will be shown in my page in application. I want to make another. Is it possible to see current pictures in external Photo viewer after button click(for example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No its not possible, currently the Windows Phone doesnt support any Functionality to provide a 3rd Party the necessary means to replace system apps ( like the photo galery).